# Encoded notebook

Tags: notebook-security

Please it's urgent.

I have an encoding problem. When I open my notebooks I find weird characters like this

[image]

Are my data erased?

Comment: Try opening your notebook in a text editor and see if you can salvage something from there, or if it's still showing the same gobbledygook there.

Comment: I opened it in BlocNotes, the same gobbledygook

Comment: You say that you have an encoding problem though: do you know if you changed the character encoding in the notebook / in your system? What was the last operation you did on this notebook? Was it recently saved, operated on, downloaded from somewhere? Do you have any more context?

Comment: @MarcoB No, I haven't changed anything, these are old notebooks written by MAT11 in 2015,  I wanted to consult them for work.

Comment: Is it possible that they were generated on another computer that had a different character encoding? Can you try to open one of these notebooks on another computer, or perhaps in the free Wolfram cloud to see if the problem persists?

Comment: @MarcoB it's always the same problem on Wolfram cloud, only  gobbledygook.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137186/discussion-between-gallagher-and-marcob).